# Angeführte/aufgeführte Beispiele

Tags: verb

Welches Verb verwendet man in solchen Kontexten wie „*in oben/unten **angeführten*** oder ***aufgeführten*** Beispielen"?

Answer (score 3):

Beide Varianten sind möglich und stilistisch gleichwertig.

---

Zu beachten ist, dass beide Wörter in anderen Zusammenhängen noch andere, unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben:

*aufführen:*

> - Wenn sich ihr Sohn weiter so **aufführt,** fliegt er von der Schule.
> - Die Bürger von Simmdorf werden morgen in Gemeindesaal die Räuber von Schiller **aufführen.**

*anführen:*

> - Susanne, wir wollen, dass du uns **anführst.** Geh du voran!
> - Herr Hase, was haben Sie zu Ihrer Verteidigung **anzuführen**?

Comment: Ich weiß von nichts!

Answer (score 3):

Ich glaube, die beiden Wörter haben, wenn auch sehr ähnlich, eine leicht unterschiedliche Bedeutung:

*Aufgeführt* erweckt den Eindruck einer relativ **vollständigen** Auflistung, einer vollständigen Liste oder Aufzählung.

*Angeführt* dagegen würde ich nehmen, wenn ich nur einige ausgewählte Beispiele **erwähne** und keinerlei Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit erheben will.

In einer Diskussion kann man z. B. wichtige Argumente *anführen* – *aufführen* wird man sie wahrscheinlich eher nicht. Zum Beispiel funktioniert meiner Meinung nach das nachfolgende Beispiel nicht – oder nicht richtig – mit *aufführen*:

> Der Abgeordnete führte als wichtiges Argument gegen das Gesetz die steuerliche Mehrbelastung von Familien an.

Answer (score 1):

Neben Deinen Verben kann man auch sagen:

- in obigen Beispielen (aber nicht: **untigen*)
- in oben stehenden Beispielen
- in oben genannten Beispielen
- in oben (auf-)gelisteten Beispielen (wenn alle unmittelbar aufeinanderfolgen)
- in oben aufgezählten Beispielen (wenn sie nummeriert sind)

Bedeutungsunterschiede sind bei allen Varianten kaum erkennbar. Nimm einfach, was Dir am besten gefällt.

---

Einen Artikel („in **den** oben …“) empfehle ich übrigens bei allen Varianten — auch bei Deinen Vorschlägen. Das kommt aber auf den Kontext an.